# Wordpress - Displaying comments on pages distinguished by GET IDs

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

Wordpress - comments_template().

I am currently trying to work with an outdated wordpress addon and I wish to add the functionality to allow commenting on certain pages.

However each page url looks like:

```
/match/?match=1
/match/?match=2
/match/?match=3
```

So when I post comments on a page they are displayed okay, however when a comment is made it appears in the 3 pages listed above rather just the one page the comment was made on.

So my question is how do I make it so comments_template() sees match=1,2,3, etc as individual pages rather than the same page with just different get statements.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is very confusing.  You need to provide more explanation, some code that you've tried etc if you want answers.

Comment: I edited it, however I am not sure what else I can add. I did mention what I have tried "comments_template()".

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using some sort of plugin to handle your comments. If thats the case, your going to have a hard time getting help. I suggest using the native WordPress comments management.

If i'm wrong, you'll need to re-explain your question because you need to explain what the 'match' get variable is and what it mean, and you need to explain more clearly whatever is your saying about comments showing up on 'the 3 pages listed above'. You did not list pages.

Comment: I am using "comments_template()" to enable comments which is a function in wordpress. As I said in my original post those matches are get statements and each match ID = a different page.

Comment: so do you mean that to say that its `/page/#` as in /page/1 or /page/2? That is the normal pagination pattern in wordpress. I realize that that items in the query are get statements, thats the case for all items in a query string. You need to explain what they actually represent - if this is custom rewrite, you should post those rewrite rules.

Comment: Or maybe what your looking for, is a method of capturing custom get variables?

Comment: Its not a rewrite, its just variables being tagged onto the end of a URL which controls what data is displayed. Just go to http://pantheones.com.au/pes-csgo-open-league/match-table/ and you will see what I am talking about and hopefully it makes everything so much more clear.

Comment: Unless you create a custom post type, that handles /match/ in the url, your going to need to write a rewrite rule to capture /match/, otherwise wordpress will think its a post or a page, or a category, etc, and when it does not find them it will return a 404. If you intend on having /match/ be a page/post/category/etc - then thats fine, but if so thats part of whats missing from your explanation.